# jquery random colors foreach div

Tags: jquery

I have this issue with my function and I'm trying to randomize some colors (predefined) to my divs and count each time a color has been used.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="change_color2" id="rand_1"></div>
<div class="change_color2" id="rand_2"></div>
<div class="change_color2" id="rand_3"></div>
<div class="change_color2" id="rand_4"></div>
<div class="change_color2" id="rand_5"></div>
```

And some divs that are going to have as background the random color:

```
<div class="change_color"></div>
```

And this is my js code:

```
function colorfy_me() {
    var myColors = [
        '#543326', '#5EC631', '#A9D7DC', '#003946', '#E0D8C8'
    ];
    shuffleArray(myColors);
    var i = 1;
    $('div.change_color').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', myColors[i]);
        i = (i + 1) % myColors.length;
    });
}    

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

But the problem is that it changes the colors randomly for the first 5 divs in sets.
And I don't know how to count each color.

I have [created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eyQX/149/)

Comment: Why shuffle the array? Just pick a random color from the array as it is. Are you not allowed to repeat the same color in the same sequence?

Comment: It's not clear for me what's the problem. What do you want different ?

Comment: You can compute how often each color is used, since you are assigning them sequentially. It's `#uses = floor(#elements / #colors) + (indexOfColor < #elements % #colors) ? 1 : 0`. Either a color is used `floor(#elements / #colors)` times or `floor(#elements / #colors) + 1` times.

Comment: hi the color can be used more than one maybe the question is not as good as i've tryed to explain. Lets say that you have 5 balls each has a different color and then you have 25 balls (not colored) and when you press the button all the 25 balls should have random color from those predefined (5 balls) the color can be like white, white, red, blue, green,yellow,blue,white,black,blue,red,red etc..

Comment: So you want to count how many balls out of 25 balls has a particular color

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SnkXt/1/ ?

Comment: If you assign the colors in sequence, i.e. color1 to element1, color2 to element2, ..., color1 to elementX, color2 to element(X+1), etc., then you can compute the number of uses directly. If you assign the colors completely randomly, then you have to explicitly keep track. But in your current code, you assign them sequentially.

Comment: @Arun: I'm having fun just pressing that button :D

Comment: @FelixKling hmmm :) ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/GXVUE/1/

It just outputs the stats into the div with class="stats".

```
(function($){

  var colors = ['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f']
    , colorsUsed = {}
    , $divsToColor = $('.random-color');

  $divsToColor.each(function(){

    var $div = $(this)
      , randomColor = colors[ Math.floor( Math.random() * colors.length ) ];

    $div.css('backgroundColor', randomColor);

    // Keeps track of how often a color is used...
    if( colorsUsed[randomColor] ){
        colorsUsed[randomColor]++;
    } else {
        colorsUsed[randomColor] = 1;
    }

  });

  // This reads through the stats.
  $('.stats').html(function(){
      var out = [];
      for( var color in colorsUsed ){
          out.push( color + ' was used ' + colorsUsed[color] + ' times.' );
      }
      return out.join('<br>');
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Personally, I try and avoid having two parallel arrays that have to be kept in sync. Much better to encapsulate the data in an object.

Comment: I agree, Matt. I prefer your method over mine and think it's better explained. I think mine was only chosen because of the demo. =)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array of just colors, why not populate your array with objects that include both the color and the number of times used. Something like this:

```
var myColors = [
    { color: '#543326', uses: 0 },
    { color: '#5EC631', uses: 0 },
    { color: '#A9D7DC', uses: 0 },
    { color: '#003946', uses: 0 },
    { color: '#E0D8C8', uses: 0 }
];
```

Then you can assign your colors like this:

```
$(this).css('background-color', myColors[i].color);
```

and track how many times you've used each color with:

```
myColors[i].uses++;
```

If you don't like writing out the object literals, you could even create a function that will take your original array of colors and convert it into objects.

```
function MakeColorObjects(arrayOfColors) {
    var objs = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arrayOfColors.length; i++) {
         objs.push({ color: arrayOfColors[i], uses: 0 });
    }
    returns objs;
}
```

If you wanted to get really clever, you could create objects that will automatically track their usage with something like this:

```
function TrackedColor(colorCode) {
    var self = this;
    var uses = 0;

    function getUses() {
        return uses;
    }

    function getColor() {
        uses++;
        return colorCode;       
    }

    function resetCount {
        uses = 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this like this:

```
var myColors = [
    new TrackedColor('#543326'), 
    new TrackedColor('#5EC631'), 
    new TrackedColor('#A9D7DC'), 
    new TrackedColor('#003946'), 
    new TrackedColor('#E0D8C8')
];
```

And:

```
$(this).css('background-color', myColors[i].getColor());
```

And you don't have to worry about forgetting to increase the number of uses, because it maintains it's own state. You can retrieve the current value with

```
myColors[i].getUses();
```

Comment: ok, i'll try this code and let you know. And big thanks to all of you for the kind support.