# Apply different colors to Dynamically generated row of HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created dynamic table using HTML and javascript but rather than applying alternate color, I want to apply distinct color to each row. How can I do so?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic Page</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Rows</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="txtRows"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Columns</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="txtCols"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="btnDisplay" value="Display" onClick="createTable();"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="tbl_DynamicTable" border="1">
        </table>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createTable()
        {
          debugger;
            var rows = document.getElementById("txtRows").value;
            var cols = document.getElementById("txtCols").value;
            var table = document.getElementById("tbl_DynamicTable");
            var str="";
            for(var i=0;i<rows;i++)
            {
                str += "<tr id=row" + i +">";

                //r = document.getElementById('tbl_DynamicTable').getElementsByTagName('<tr>');
                //r.bgColor = colours[(i%k)/group | 0];

                //mycurrent_row.style.backgroundColor = "#EEF4EA";
                //mycurrent_row.style.backgroundColor =colours[(i%k)/group | 0];

                for(var j=0;j<cols;j++)
                {
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        str += "<th> Header " + j + "</th>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        str += "<td> Row " + i + ", Cell "+ j + "</td>";
                    }
                }
                str += "</tr>";             
            }           
            table.innerHTML = str;
        }       


        $("tr").style("bgcolor","red");     
    </script>
</html>
```

I don't know how to use jQuery with HTML page. I'm new to this. So if possible please let me know what is needed to include in this too.

Comment: Show us some code first

Comment: **you have the same question here too.. didn't this help** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488195/how-can-i-apply-dynamically-color-to-each-row-differently-to-html-table asked by yourself

Comment: How about [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896929/jquery-random-colors-foreach-div)

Comment: no it won't because I need some more details as I'm the begginer of jQuery and Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many way to create a random color.

Use these example :

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

**jQuery**

```
(function(m,s,c){return (c ? arguments.callee(m,s,c-1) : '#') +
  s[m.floor(m.random() * s.length)]})(Math,'0123456789ABCDEF',5)
```

And add this hexa random color on your TR when you generate it

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
                  ^ Here
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Other example on http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/

Comment: But I'm generating row dynamically, I don't know how to access its bgColor property...

Comment: When you write `str += "<tr id=row" + i +">";`, Add the property bgcolor like this `<tr id=row" + i +" bgcolor="+ RandomColor+">";` where `RandomColor` is generated by `'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);`

Comment: its showing error: Uncaught typeError: object Function(e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'random'

Comment: I have no error with the random : http://jsfiddle.net/Uwgn9/ or the other method : http://jsfiddle.net/Uwgn9/1/

Comment: Can you please let me know this by editing it in my code? If is it ok with you.

Answer (score 2):

javascript approach (i suggest including jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

// paint rows on document ready
$(function(){
    paint_rows();
});

function paint_rows() {
    $('#table_id tr').each(function(){
            $(this).css('color', get_random_color());
    });
}
</script>
```

just make sure to add enough color values into the array `colors` (can use hex values as well).

and, you can call the function `paint_rows()` whenever needed of course.

hope that helps.

Comment: How can I apply this function to the dynamically generated ROW's bgColor property? Any idea?

Comment: change `$(this).css('color', get_random_color());` to `$(this).css('background', get_random_color());`