# Trying to randomize div color when mouse enters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have it so that each square is a different color when the user hovers over it once the "randomize" button is clicked. Nothing changes when I chose the randomize function. Here's my code:

```
function randomSetup(numOfSquares){

    var numSquares = numOfSquares;
    var squareSide = 500 / numSquares;
    var totalSquares = numSquares * numSquares;


    for(var rows = 0; rows < totalSquares; rows++){
    $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
    }

    var colors = randomColor();

    $('.container').on('mouseenter', '.gridSquare', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(colors,colors,colors)');
    });

    $('.gridSquare').width(squareSide);
    $('.gridSquare').height(squareSide);

}

function randomColor(){

    return Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 1;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLonz7c0/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery random colors foreach div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896929/jquery-random-colors-foreach-div)

Comment: `randomColor` should probably be `randomNumber` as it only returns a number and not a real color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/oLonz7c0/7/

Trippy.

Regenerate the random colors inside the event handler so each square is a different color.

```
$('.container').on('mouseenter', '.gridSquare', function(){

    var colors = [];
    colors[0] = Math.round(randomColor());
    colors[1] = Math.round(randomColor());
    colors[2] = Math.round(randomColor());       

    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb('+colors[0]+','+colors[1]+','+colors[2]+')');
});
```

Comment: Why the array? And the `Math.round()` call should be made in `randomColor`

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid:

```
'rgb(colors,colors,colors)'
```

Try this:

```
$('.container').on('mouseenter', '.gridSquare', function(){
    var red = randomColor();
    var green = randomColor();
    var blue = randomColor();

    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+')');
});
```

You also need to round your random number:

```
function randomColor(){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oLonz7c0/21/

Comment: _so that each square is a different color_ With this all tiles will have the same color

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like

```
function randomColor(){
     var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"];                
     var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);   
    //return Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 1;
    return colors[rand];
}
```

And

```
var colors ='';



    $('.container').on('mouseenter', '.gridSquare', function(){
        colors = randomColor();
        $(this).css('background-color',colors );
    });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/oLonz7c0/14/